# MonoGame 3.3 Font loading

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

Is there any way to have fonts in game without making a separate Content Project and adding a .spritefont file in the new 3.3 Monogame? You can now load other resources directly from the Content folder but not spritefonts...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that the Content.mcgb is actually a little GUI helper and you can generate and easily load a .spritefont file with it.

Steps:

1.Load the GUI app by double clicking the "Content.mcgb" file in the "Content" folder

2.Go to Edit -> New Item... -> Choose SpriteFont and give it a name -> Hit "Ok"

3.Go to Build -> Build (or hit F6) - You should get some info on the font getting built

4.Load the .spritefont file in VS 
(Right-click the projct -> Add -> Existing Item -> Choose the newly created file)

Comment: Even though you made this answer yourself, you should still remember to mark it as such. :)

Comment: I had no ideea. Isn't that done automatically? I'm new to stackexchange :) Also, how does marking it change anything?

Comment: It isn't done automatically. Below the upvote/downvote arrows there's a button to accept the answer. Marking it means the question has been answered, and when someone comes looking in the future, they'll see the answer that solved your problem right away.

Answer (score -2):

Incidentally, if you use MonoGame 3.3, you can just add a new SpriteFont to the MonoGame Pipeline and it works automatically :)

Comment: MonoGame 3.3 is exactly what this question is asking about, perhaps you should explain these steps more.

Comment: Oops, it seems you're correct, my mistake.  It looks like the marked answer above actually outlines it perfectly :)